# Accessing un-mapped entities from Entity Framework SqlQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework, I have an entities class which has 2 fields:

- Name
- Description

I have a stored procedure which is returning exact above entities plus an additional entity called `TotalRecords`. I created a new entity in my above class called `TotalRecords` and added an attribute `[NotMapped]` to it.

Now when I call the stored procedure, it does not map to the new entity `TotalRecords`; I understand because I have added an attribute `[NotMapped]` on it, but if I don't apply that attribute, it will simply create a new column in my database table, which isn't my intention.

Here's how I am calling `SqlQuery` to execute stored procedure:

```
var _products = db.Products.SqlQuery("GetProductsByCategory @p0,@p1,@p2", categoryID, pageIndex, Common.PAGE_SIZE).ToList();
```

Could anyone tell me how could I get the `TotalRecords` field from stored procedure, without adding new column in the database? As I said above, I have just one column extra rest all are being mapped to the database table `Products`

Comment: As I know, you want to return 3 fields (Name, Description, TotalRecords) from the Stored procedure, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create an object that has the same property names as the results returned by the stored procedure. You can try following the sample. Hope to help, my friend.

1) The first, create a class like this:

```
public class ProductResult
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public decimal TotalRecords { get; set; }
    }
```

2) And then call the procedure:

```
using(var context = new DatabaseContext())
    {
            var categoryIdParameter = new SqlParameter("@p0", categoryID);
            var pageIndexParameter = new SqlParameter("@p1", pageIndex);
            var pageSizeParameter = new SqlParameter("@p2", Common.PAGE_SIZE);

            var result = context.Database
                .SqlQuery<ProductResult>("GetProductsByCategory @p0, @p1, @p2", categoryIdParameter, pageIndexParameter, pageSizeParameter)
                .ToList();
    }
```

The result will contain a list of ProductResult objects.

Comment: But this would add the Property (TotalRecords) in the database, because the ProductResult model is mapped to database.

Comment: @Abbas: Could you show the Stored Procedure GetProductsByCategory?